# Non-Primary Unique Not Joinable in Entity Framework Database First

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to use EF 6.1.3 to use a Unique constraint for my EF model from Database to EF model.  I've examples this done from Code-First, but I can't seem to update my models from the existing database with this schema.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Applications]
(
   [ApplicantId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
   [Name] VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
   [StateCode] VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL,
   CONSTRAINT [FK_Applications_ToStates] FOREIGN KEY ([State]) REFERENCES [States]([StateCode]),
)
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[States]
(
   [StateId] INT NOT NULL IDENTITY, 
   [StateCode] VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL  , 
   [StateName] VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL, 
   CONSTRAINT [PK_States] PRIMARY KEY ([StateId]), 
   CONSTRAINT [AK_States_StateCode] UNIQUE ([StateCode]) 
)
```

I get the following error:

> > Severity  Code    Description Project File    Line
> >     Warning     Error 6035: The relationship 'FK_Applications_ToStates' has columns that are not part of the key of the table on the primary side of the relationship. The relationship was excluded.

EF does not support non number-based Primary Keys as far as I know either.

Comment: So are your trying to reverse engineer using EF Power Tools or is this Database First with an edmx?

Comment: Database first with an edmx

Comment: You'll have to do that on the database side then. Sounds like it is coming in EF 7 though: https://data.uservoice.com/forums/72025-entity-framework-feature-suggestions/suggestions/1050579-unique-constraint-i-e-candidate-key-support

Comment: It's been coming since EF 4 sadly

Comment: EF can create FK relationships only to PK of the "principal" (i.e. in your case `Applications` table should have `StateId` column instead of  `StateCode`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the CodePlex of EF, this is an open issue, and the second most requested feature.  There is no way to deal with this issue at the time, and I'll have to try and code around it

http://entityframework.codeplex.com/workitem/299